# Error html format when using WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: html, liferay, wysiwyg

I got problem with feature display html source of **WYSIWYG** editor.

1. Writing a html source in editor like this:

https://prntscr.com/lratw7

2. Click to source button to display normal, after click again my html formatted to something else.

https://prntscr.com/lrau2w

Why ?

How can i save original html ?

First i can save original html, but after the next edit original html lost ?

Please help me.

This is liferay 6.2.

Comment: Hi, please, post your code in this website along with the links so we can all see and help. Some of us will not follow links to external resources.

Comment: By the way, without seen the code, it seems you are describing an usual editor filter. One cannot pot arbitrary code inside the editor, as some tags/content are normally harmful, for security or compatibility reasons; thus, they are filtered. Please check your configuration to indicate the editor you are using to provide the WYSIWYG editor. Then, follow that editor filtering documentation to white list the content you want.